# Wrong indentation on paste switch/case php

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCODE, whenever I paste the case part of a switch statement I get the wrong indentation.

[image]

How can I fix this? If possible while maintaining format on paste since this feature works fine on every other case.

```php
<?php

switch ($variable) {
    case 'value':
        # code...
        break;
    
    case 'value':
        # code...
        break;
    
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
?>
```

#### Update:

[image]

When pressing Ctrl + Z the indentation gets fixed.
Checking `Editor: Format On Paste` does fix the problem.

As for what extensions might affect this, only **PHP Intelephense**, but I don't see any setting that might control formatting on paste aside from `Editor: Format On Paste`

Comment: what if you add the closing tag (`?>`)? Does the issue still happen then? Also, can you please provde the text of that repro shown in your gif to make it easier for others to reproduce the issue? On my machine, it look like one can at least work around it by copying the leading newline, and then pasting on a new line with the same indent level as the break statement. Would that be an acceptable answer to you?

Comment: Do you have any PHP extensions installed? If so, provide a link to their marketplace page(s).

Comment: @user just opening a new tab and adding the php code I get the wrong indentation, shift + alt + f to format shows the `There's no formatter for 'php' files installed`, `Editor: Format On Paste` is unchecked, however checking that setting does fix the issue. I'll update the main post with this and the extensions that might affect this.

Comment: @user pasting on a new line with the same indent level as the break statement also sets the correct indentation for me.

Comment: Nice findings! If you're satisfied with what you and I found, you could write up an answer post ([answer])

Comment: I'll write it as an answer just to have it visible but I won't accept it just in case there's a different way to fix this. The fact that pasting and pressing Ctrl-Z makes the identation correct makes me think that there's some kind of formatting going on.

Comment: @user I opened a GH Bug Issue, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174667 turns out in C# and Java the indentation when copy&pasting is correct

Answer (score 0):

#### Somewhat of a FIX:

Just as @user said, copying the leading new line and then pasting on the following line to `break;` at the same indentation seems to paste with the correct indentation.

[image]

The fact that pasting and pressing Ctrl-Z makes the identation correct makes me think that there's some kind of formatting going on, so please let me know if you know what's going on.